# Iniciar programa Windows Forms em segundo plano

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

Desenvolvi uma aplicação de monitoramento utilizando Windows Forms, porém ela não tem necessidade de ter nada visual no momento, então eu gostaria que ao executar ela, ela fosse executada em segundo plano (gostaria que o ícone ficasse onde fica os ícones de anti-vírus,etc.).

Não tenho muita experiência com aplicações Desktop e não estou conseguindo achar uma maneira de se fazer isso, alguém poderia ajudar?

Comment: Tenho um projeto pessoal no GitHub, um [mini servidor web feito em C#](https://github.com/masbicudo/Mini-Web-Server), que faz exatamente isso. Ele inicia somente com um ícone na barra de notificação do Windows, e quando clica nele com o botão direito aparece um menu com as opções do programa, quando clica com o esquerdo aparece uma tela de terminal, mostrando os eventos de log.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Minimizar a aplicação para o *system tray* é feito com o controle `NotifyIcon` do Visual Studio.

`NotifyIcon` está no namespace *System.Windows.Forms*.

## 1. Controle NotifyIcon

Arraste e solte o controle `NotifyIcon` para o seu *form* e coloque o nome no mesmo de *notifyIcon1*.

## 2. Alterando o ícone do NotifyIcon

Precisamos alterar ícone do `NotifyIcon` para que o mesmo apareça no system tray, caso contrário nada irá mostrar. Para isso, coloque a seguinte linha de código no construtor do seu form:

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    notifyIcon1.Icon = new Icon(GetType(), "placeholder.ico");
}
```

O ícone deve ser um .ico e deve ser definido como *EmbeddedResource* nas propriedades do ícone depois que adicioná-lo no projeto.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

## 3. Configurando o form

No .cs do seu Form, coloque o seguinte:

```
private bool allowVisible;

protected override void SetVisibleCore(bool value) {
    if (!allowVisible) {
        value = false;
        if (!this.IsHandleCreated) CreateHandle();
    }
    base.SetVisibleCore(value);
}

protected override void OnFormClosing(FormClosingEventArgs e) {
    if (!allowClose) {
        this.Hide();
         e.Cancel = true;
    }
    base.OnFormClosing(e);
}
```

## 3. Mostrando a aplicação

Coloque o código abaixo no evento `DoubleClick` do controle `NotifyIcon` para exibir a sua aplicação ao dar um duplo clique no ícone no *system tray*:

```
private void notifyIcon1_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
     allowVisible = true;
     Show();
}
```

Feito isso, assim que iniciar sua aplicação, a mesma irá direto para o *system tray* com o ícone que definiu anteriormente. Para abrir a aplicação, basta dar um duplo clique em cima do ícone no *system tray*.

Comment: Esse código precisa que um formulário seja renderizado para mostrar o ícone de notificação, e encerra a aplicação quando o formulário for fechado. Isso é uma execução em primeiro plano e não acho que seja o que o AP pediu.

Comment: @Renan Não mesmo. Apenas mudei a lógica de mostrar e esconder o form e funcionou perfeitamente. Espero que não tenha dado downvote só por que achou que não iria funcionar.

Comment: Justo. Alterei meu voto para positivo.

Comment: @Renan Justo. Obrigado.

Comment: O que me surpreendeu é que chamar o método `hide` do formulário o remove da barra de tarefas. Eu não sabia que isso era possível.

Answer (score 4):

Se você der uma olhada rápida no arquivo *Program.cs* do seu projeto, você provavelmente vai ver algo parecido com:

```
static class Program
{
    /// <summary>
    /// The main entry point for the application.
    /// </summary>
    [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        Application.Run(new Form1());
    }
}
```

Ênfase em:

```
Application.Run(new Form1());
```

O método `Run` possui mais de uma sobrecarga, e a padrão é não receber parâmetro algum. Remova o seu formulário, i.e.: altere o código para:

```
Application.Run();
```

E veja como a sua aplicação inicia sem nenhuma janela aberta.

Você também não vai ter nada na barra de tarefas, então apenas com isso fica complicado até mesmo fechar o programa. Você só vai conseguir fechá-lo com o monitor de tarefas (<kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>ALT</kbd><kbd>DEL</kbd>).

Ok, vamos fazer mais algumas alterações. Adicione os seguintes namespaces:

```
using System.Drawing; // esse é só pra encurtar o uso de uma classe de ícone
using System.reflection; // esse a gente usa pra pegar o ícone da aplicação
```

Agora adicione um ícone de notificação. Ele é um objeto da classe [`System.Windows.Forms.NotifyIcon`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.windows.forms.notifyicon(v=vs.110).aspx) e não precisa estar preso a nenhum formulário :)

```
NotifyIcon ni = new NotifyIcon()
{
    Icon = Icon.ExtractAssociatedIcon(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location), // pega o ícone da aplicação
    Text = "hello",
    Visible = true // porque o padrão para "Visible" é falso
};
```

O código completo parece com isso:

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Whatever
{
    static class Program
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// The main entry point for the application.
        /// </summary>
        [STAThread]
        static void Main()
        {
            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);

            NotifyIcon ni = new NotifyIcon()
            {
                Icon = Icon.ExtractAssociatedIcon(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location),
                Text = "hello"
            };
            Application.Run();
        }
    }
}
```

Deixo a seu critério agora:

- Rodar qualquer lógica das demais classes que você tenha implementado;
- Adicionar eventos ao ícone de notificação para abrir e fechar seus formulários;
- Tratar o fechamento da aplicação para removê-lo da bandeja do sistema.